# Путь к текущей обоине Windows 10

Tags: windows, реестр

Как найти путь до конкретного файла, являющегося текущей обоиной Windows10. Хочу написать скрипт, который бы удалял текущую обоину из папки с обоями при режиме показа обоев "Слайд шоу". По аналогии с Windows 7 найти не удается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь к обоине в Windows10 (в Windows8 кажется аналогично) при слайд-шоу хранится в параметре реестра `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\TranscodedImageCache`. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Правда хранится он в бинарном виде. Вот пример на PowerShell, который выдергивает значение реестра и выдает путь к текущим обоям.

```
PS Z:\> $bytes=(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\TranscodedImageCache") 
PS Z:\> $path=([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes[24..($bytes.length-1)]) -split "\0")[0]
PS Z:\> $path
C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Theme1\img1.jpg
```